# Debian Postfix distribution list accessible only for few adresses

Tags: postfix, distribution-lists, restrictions

Actually I'm working with Postfix server and trying to implement distribution list with simple restrictions.

My assumptions:
I created alias:
*managers@mydomain.com* -> *manager1@mydomain.com, manager2@mydomain.com, manager3@mydomain.com*

I want to restrict *managers@mydomain.com* that wway, that only
*boss@mydomain.com 
manager2@mydomain.com*
can write to managers list.

According to [http://postfix.cs.utah.edu/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html#internal][1]

I created in FILE *main.cf:*

```
  ...
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
...  
check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access,
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/protected_destinations,
...
smtpd_restriction_classes = insiders_only
    insiders_only = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/insiders, reject
```

FILE */etc/postfix/protected_destinations*:

```
...
managers@mydomain.com   insiders_only
...
```

FILE *insiders*:

```
boss@mydomain.com OK
manager2@mydomain.com OK
```

But it works by blocking all incoming emails from outside.
As I wrote before, my intention is to let only addresses from managers_sender_list to write to managers@mydomain.com 
and let other activity be done in normal way.

The question is: how to implement these assumptions properly ?